# elasticsearch: getMinuteOfDay() applied to time() in date range filter

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to build an elasticsearch query to return documents for times between midnight and the current time of day, for all dates. For example, if I run the query at 09:00:00, then the query will return any document with a timestamp between midnight and 09:00:00 regardless of the date.

Here's an example dataset:

```
curl -XPUT  localhost:9200/test/dt/_mapping -d '{"dt" : {"properties" : {"created_at" : {"type" : "date", "format": "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss" }}}}'

curl -XPOST localhost:9200/test/dt/1 -d '{ "created_at": "2014-10-09 07:00:00" }'
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/test/dt/2 -d '{ "created_at": "2014-10-09 14:00:00" }'
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/test/dt/3 -d '{ "created_at": "2014-10-08 08:00:00" }'
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/test/dt/4 -d '{ "created_at": "2014-10-08 15:00:00" }'
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/test/dt/5 -d '{ "created_at": "2014-10-07 09:00:00" }'
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/test/dt/6 -d '{ "created_at": "2014-10-07 16:00:00" }'
```

and an example filter:

```
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/test/dt/_search?pretty -d '{
  "query": {
    "filtered" : {
       "filter" : {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "script" : {
            "script" : "doc[\"created_at\"].date.getMinuteOfDay() < 600"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

where 600 is a static parameter that I want to replace with a dynamic minutes parameter depending on the time of day when the query is run.

My best attempt is to use the getMinuteOfDay() method to filter each doc, but my problem is how to get getMinuteOfDay() for the current time. I've tried variations using time() instead of the hard-coded parameter 600 in the above query, but can't figure it out.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty late but this can be done with `DateTime.now()`, you should change your query to

```
GET test/dt/_search
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "script": {
                "script": "doc[\"created_at\"].date.getMinuteOfDay() < DateTime.now().getMinuteOfDay()"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Hope this helps!