# Get objects by time range in a date field elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

I have a date field in document mapping in elasticsearch called conversationSMPostDate,

```
"conversationSMPostDate": {
"format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss",
"type": "date"
}
```

I want to get some stats on the data within a **time range from midnight to 9a.m**.

I tried to combine multiple wildcards using a filter, it did not work out. I searched and couldn't find a way to do this.I want to do something similar to this
[elasticsearch: getMinuteOfDay() applied to time() in date range filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26286503/elasticsearch-getminuteofday-applied-to-time-in-date-range-filter)

Comment: I have answered the [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26286503/elasticsearch-getminuteofday-applied-to-time-in-date-range-filter/34457972#34457972) you referred, let me know If you does not work

Answer (score 0):

Hi I am not sure how this will work out in elasticsearch but with `lucene-core` you can use it as below

```
public class TestLuceneDate {

    private static final String DETAILS = "details";
    private static Path path = Paths.get("/luceneindex");
    private static final SimpleDateFormat DATE_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    private static final String DATE = "date";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        index();
        search("1988-04-08 03:00:00", "1988-04-08 16:00:00");
    }

    private static void index() throws Exception {
        Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer();
        IndexWriterConfig config = new IndexWriterConfig(analyzer);
        Directory directory = FSDirectory.open(path);
        IndexWriter writer = new IndexWriter(directory, config);
        writer.addDocument(newDocument("document with date 1", "1988-04-08 00:05:12"));
        writer.addDocument(newDocument("document with date 2", "1988-04-08 04:20:00"));
        writer.addDocument(newDocument("document with date 3", "1988-04-08 11:13:50"));
        writer.addDocument(newDocument("document with date 4", "1988-04-08 15:07:05"));
        writer.addDocument(newDocument("document with date 5", "1988-04-08 18:14:33"));
        writer.addDocument(newDocument("document with date 6", "1988-04-08 19:20:47"));
        writer.addDocument(newDocument("document with date 7", "1988-04-08 22:16:07"));
        writer.addDocument(newDocument("document with date 8", "1988-04-08 23:44:98"));
        writer.close();
    }

    private static Document newDocument(String details, String date) throws Exception {
        Document document = new Document();
        document.add(new TextField(DETAILS, details, Store.YES));
        document.add(new LongField(DATE, DATE_FORMAT.parse(date).getTime(), Store.YES));
        return document;
    }

    private static void search(String fromDateString, String toDateString) throws Exception {
        Directory directory = FSDirectory.open(path);
        IndexReader inxRead = DirectoryReader.open(directory);
        IndexSearcher is = new IndexSearcher(inxRead);
        Long fromDate = DATE_FORMAT.parse(fromDateString).getTime();
        Long toDate = DATE_FORMAT.parse(toDateString).getTime();
        NumericRangeQuery<Long> dateRangeQuery = NumericRangeQuery.newLongRange(DATE, fromDate, toDate, true, true);
        TopDocs hits = is.search(dateRangeQuery, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        for (ScoreDoc scoreDoc : hits.scoreDocs) {
            Document doc = is.doc(scoreDoc.doc);
            System.out.println("Parser > " + scoreDoc.score + " :: " + doc.get(DETAILS) + " - " + DATE_FORMAT.format(new Date(Long.parseLong(doc.get(DATE)))));
        }
        inxRead.close();
    }
}
```

I have used Lucene 5.1.0 to do this.